# Flink 1.14 : Why can't resotore savepoint got error Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.messages.FlinkJobNotFoundException: Could not find Flink job

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-cep, savepoints

I'm trying to restore a savepoint which is save to my local tmp folder.However i got below error when i trying to restore it.Do you have any idea about this ?

/home/chinthakasajith/flink-1.14.0$ ./bin/flink run -m 127.0.0.1:28080  --detached --fromSavepoint /tmp/chinthakasajith/flink-savepoints/savepoint-59ec96-57150593c638 /home/chinthakasajith/cast-1.0.jar

---

The program finished with the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.messages.FlinkJobNotFoundException: Could not find Flink job (18e42cc9a521f3b2a7621cf62a7495f1)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.Dispatcher.requestExecutionGraphInfo(Dispatcher.java:627)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(AkkaRpcActor.java:316)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:314)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:217)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:78)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:163)
at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24)
at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20)
at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20)
at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is thrown by the Job Manager. To find the root cause of this problem, look in the Task Manager logs.